# Ubuntu: Check the sound card line input on a remote machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, audio, sound-card

How to check from the command line on a remote machine (ssh) if the line input of sound card has an audio signal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to be using ubuntu:

```
arecord -vv /dev/null
```

should display you a set of statistics plus a moving bar of hashes that goes right or left according to the input level of the sound input.

Comment: as the last line I have this:
#+                                                | 00%
It means that I have no input? Right?

Comment: The bar refers to the pink (microphone) or the light blue (line-in) connector on sound card?

Comment: Correct, you have no input on the line. AFAIK, the bar refers to whatever you have configured via alsa as input channel. You can check your settings still with CLI by issuing the command `alsamixer`. The TAB key allows you to switch between panes, arrows navigate and change values.

Comment: Really Thanks. In alsamiker I have the input line set to 0, now I have increased the value. Tomorrow I try to insert the jack into the input line, now in alsamixer Mic = CAPTUR, so I think I'm using the microphone connector instead of the input line.

Comment: The best way to thank on SU is to upvote the answer if it is useful, and to accept it if/when it solves the issue (just mentioning as I see you are new to the platform. Until you will have reputation points, however, you won't be able to upvote any answer!) Let me know if you make any progress! Good luck! :)

Comment: Fixed! The Jack was inserted into the right connector, 
I needed only to press the spacebar on 'Line' item in alsamixer to enable.

Comment: The 'thank you upvote' can come from an innocent by-stander as well...